# What methods do I use to manipulate data of an array within an Object? (Pseudo Code only)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, methods

Backstory (skipable):

Hello, I'm a student at Lambda school.  Recently we had a JS assessment test in order to progress to the next unit, but I wounded up flunking it twice.  So now I have to repeat Unit 1.  I'm here today in order to finally knock out that damn exam.  I don't have a problem working with Arrays or Objects, what I do have a problem with is figuring out a way to solve issues when they are combined.  It's like:  "What the hell, do I use map or Object.Key?"  Those types of problems appeared throughout the exam.  It's fine to challenge students, but I never worked with both at the same time before.  The approach was completely lost on me and before I knew it, my 3 hours were up two days straight.

What I hope you can provide:

I'm going to provide one problem and show you the work that I did.  What I would like is for you to formulate pseudo code for me to work out that problem.  I need to learn how to use Pseudo code if I want to be a good web engineer.  Please do not solve the problem for me, all I ask is pseudo code.  I'll try to work on the problem based on the pseudo code I feel is manageable for me to do.  Thanks in Advance.

Problem and current Status:

```
/**
 * ### Challenge `getSecondStarshipName`
 * MVP Challenge 
 *
 * @instructions
 * Return second starship's name from `starships` property.
 * If length is 0. Return 'none'
 */
function getSecondStarshipName(character) {
  // TODO: Add your code here.

  const checkProperty = character.hasOwnProperty("starships");
  const checkArray = character.isArray("starships");
  const secondShipLength = character.starships[1].length;
  const secondShipName = character.starships[1].name;

  if (checkProperty && checkArray) {
    if (secondShipLength >= 2) {
      return secondShipName;
    } else {
      return "none";
    }
  } else {
    return "none";
  }
}
```

Data

```
window.lukeSkywalker = require('./person-1.json')
window.leiaOrgana = require('./person-5.json')
window.obiWanKenobi = require('./person-10.json')

},{"./person-1.json":2,"./person-10.json":3,"./person-5.json":4}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports={
  "name": "Luke Skywalker",
  "height": "172",
  "mass": "77",
  "hair_color": "blond",
  "skin_color": "fair",
  "eye_color": "blue",
  "birth_year": "19BBY",
  "homeworld": "Tatooine",
  "films": [
    "A New Hope",
    "The Empire Strikes Back",
    "Return of the Jedi",
    "Revenge of the Sith",
    "The Force Awakens"
  ],
  "species": [
    "Human"
  ],
  "vehicles": [
    {
      "name": "Snowspeeder",
      "model": "t-47 airspeeder",
      "manufacturer": "Incom corporation",
      "cost_in_credits": null,
      "length": "4.5",
      "max_atmosphering_speed": "650",
      "crew": 2,
      "passengers": 0,
      "cargo_capacity": "10"
    },
    {
      "name": "Imperial Speeder Bike",
      "model": "74-Z speeder bike",
      "manufacturer": "Aratech Repulsor Company",
      "cost_in_credits": 8000,
      "length": "3",
      "max_atmosphering_speed": "360",
      "crew": 1,
      "passengers": 1,
      "cargo_capacity": "4"
    }
  ],
  "starships": [
    {
      "name": "X-wing",
      "model": "T-65 X-wing",
      "manufacturer": "Incom Corporation",
      "cost_in_credits": 149999,
      "length": "12.5",
      "max_atmosphering_speed": "1050",
      "crew": 1,
      "passengers": 0,
      "cargo_capacity": "110",
      "consumables": "1 week",
      "hyperdrive_rating": "1.0",
      "MGLT": "100",
      "starship_class": "Starfighter"
    },
    {
      "name": "Imperial shuttle",
      "model": "Lambda-class T-4a shuttle",
      "manufacturer": "Sienar Fleet Systems",
      "cost_in_credits": 240000,
      "length": "20",
      "max_atmosphering_speed": "850",
      "crew": 6,
      "passengers": 20,
      "cargo_capacity": "80000",
      "consumables": "2 months",
      "hyperdrive_rating": "1.0",
      "MGLT": "50",
      "starship_class": "Armed government transport"
    }
  ],
  "created": "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z",
  "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z",
  "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/1/"
}
},{}],3:[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports={
  "name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
  "height": "182",
  "mass": "77",
  "hair_color": "auburn, white",
  "skin_color": "fair",
  "eye_color": "blue-gray",
  "birth_year": "57BBY",
  "gender": "male",
  "homeworld": "Stewjon",
  "films": [
    "A New Hope",
    "The Empire Strikes Back",
    "Return of the Jedi",
    "The Phantom Menace",
    "Attack of the Clones",
    "Revenge of the Sith"
  ],
  "species": [
    "Human"
  ],
  "vehicles": [
    {
      "name": "Tribubble bongo",
      "model": "Tribubble bongo",
      "manufacturer": "Otoh Gunga Bongameken Cooperative",
      "cost_in_credits": null,
      "length": "15",
      "max_atmosphering_speed": "85",
      "crew": 1,
      "passengers": 2,
      "cargo_capacity": "1600"
    }
  ],
  "starships": [
    {
      "name": "Jedi starfighter",
      "model": "Delta-7 Aethersprite-class interceptor",
      "manufacturer": "Kuat Systems Engineering",
      "cost_in_credits": 180000,
      "length": "8",
      "max_atmosphering_speed": "1150",
      "crew": 1,
      "passengers": 0,
      "cargo_capacity": "60",
      "consumables": "7 days"
    },
    {
      "name": "Trade Federation cruiser",
      "model": "Providence-class carrier/destroyer",
      "manufacturer": "Rendili StarDrive, Free Dac Volunteers Engineering corps.",
      "cost_in_credits": 125000000,
      "length": "1088",
      "max_atmosphering_speed": "1050",
      "crew": 600,
      "passengers": 48247,
      "cargo_capacity": "50000000",
      "consumables": "4 years"
    },
    {
      "name": "Naboo star skiff",
      "model": "J-type star skiff",
      "manufacturer": "Theed Palace Space Vessel Engineering Corps/Nubia Star Drives, Incorporated",
      "cost_in_credits": null,
      "length": "29.2",
      "max_atmosphering_speed": "1050",
      "crew": 3,
      "passengers": 3,
      "cargo_capacity": null,
      "consumables": null
    },
    {
      "name": "Jedi Interceptor",
      "model": "Eta-2 Actis-class light interceptor",
      "manufacturer": "Kuat Systems Engineering",
      "cost_in_credits": 320000,
      "length": "5.47",
      "max_atmosphering_speed": "1500",
      "crew": 1,
      "passengers": 0,
      "cargo_capacity": "60",
      "consumables": "2 days"
    },
    {
      "name": "Belbullab-22 starfighter",
      "model": "Belbullab-22 starfighter",
      "manufacturer": "Feethan Ottraw Scalable Assemblies",
      "cost_in_credits": 168000,
      "length": "6.71",
      "max_atmosphering_speed": "1100",
      "crew": 1,
      "passengers": 0,
      "cargo_capacity": "140",
      "consumables": "7 days"
    }
  ],
  "created": "2014-12-10T16:16:29.192000Z",
  "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.325000Z",
  "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/10/"
}
},{}],4:[function(require,module,exports){
module.exports={
  "name": "Leia Organa",
  "height": "150",
  "mass": "49",
  "hair_color": "brown",
  "skin_color": "light",
  "eye_color": "brown",
  "birth_year": "19BBY",
  "gender": "female",
  "homeworld": "Alderaan",
  "films": [
      "A New Hope",
      "The Empire Strikes Back",
      "Return of the Jedi",
      "Revenge of the Sith",
      "The Force Awakens"
  ],
  "species": [
      "Human"
  ],
  "vehicles": [
    {
      "name": "Imperial Speeder Bike",
      "model": "74-Z speeder bike",
      "manufacturer": "Aratech Repulsor Company",
      "cost_in_credits": 8000,
      "length": "3",
      "max_atmosphering_speed": "360",
      "crew": 1,
      "passengers": 1,
      "cargo_capacity": "4"
    }
  ],
  "starships": [],
  "created": "2014-12-10T15:20:09.791000Z",
  "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.315000Z",
  "url": "https://swapi.co/api/people/5/"
}
},{}]},{},[1]);
```

How I would approach the problem (Pseudo Code):

```
//Create a variable called starship2nd
//Assign starship2nd the 2nd starship of each character.
//Check the length of the 2nd starship of each character.  [[I'm stuck on this phase.]]
//Return 'none' after the checker function iterates through the Object's array. [[[Not sure how to do this part either..]]
```

Failed Solutions (Are they repairable?  O_O)

solution 1 (failed)

```
const starship2nd = character.starships[1].name
const shipLength = starship2nd.length

function checkLength () {

if (shipLength === 0) {

return 'none'

}

 return checkLength()
```

Thank you for your time.  ^_^

Comment: Why do you want pseudo code if your assignment is in Javascript?

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis pseudo code isn't a specific type of language, he is just asking for general ideas of how to solve it

Comment: Please show us what you've tried that isn't working

Comment: check if the `starship` array has length 2, if yes return `index 1` element same as you are returning first element.

Comment: @JaredSmith

Here's what I tried that didn't work:

`const shipLength = starship2nd.length'
'function checkLength () {if (shipLength === 0) {return 'none'}'

`return checkLength()}`

That's really all I could think of doing.

Comment: @FINALBOSS please edit that into the question rather than posting as a comment.

Comment: Ok, I'll add a list of solutions that failed, starting with this one.  Thank you.  @JaredSmith

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code for you

```
if (character has property 'starships' and it is an array) {
  if (length of starships is at least 2) {
    return name property of second starship
  } else {
    return none
  }
} else {
  return none
}
```

You might think that some of those checks are overkill and not necessary since you know your input, but it is always good practice to double check properties and lengths before you begin accessing and assuming.

I hope that helps you with reasoning about the problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that looks very viable.  I'll show my work after I get it into a working solution.

Comment: I think i did the syntax wrong, care to proof read it for me? @ChrisG

Comment: You should go back and reread the pseudo code, especially the second if statement. What are you really checking the length of?